# Voice-over gets stuck and loops on my UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

With voice-over you can swipe right continually to take a tour of UIElements. The problem I am facing is that when voice-over gets to the last tableview cell, swiping right causes voice-over focus to jump to the first table view cell instead of continuing on to the bottom navigation bar items.

Desired behavior, when the last cell is on focus and the user swipes right then the focus should shift to the next views.

```
    embeddedTableViewCell.isAccessibilityElement = false
    embeddedTableViewCell.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true

    //TableView is a subview of embeddedTableViewCell
    tableview.isAccessibilityElement = false
    tableview.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true

    //activityItemCell is a subview of tableview
    activityItemCell.isAccessibilityElement = true
    activityItemCell.subViews.forEach { $0.isAccessibilityElement = false }
```